# How to shard on user id with hdfs?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'd like to use a hadoop/hdfs-based system, but I'm a bit concerned as I think I will want to have all data for one user on the same physical machine. Is there a way of accomplishing this in the hadoop-based universe?

Answer (score 0):

During hdfs data write process, the datablock is written first in to node from which the client is accessing the cluster if the node is a datanode.

In order to solve your problem. The edge nodes will also be datanodes. Edge nodes are from where the user starts interacting to the cluster.

But using datanodes as edgenodes has some disadvantages. One of them include Data distribution. The data distribution will not be even and if the node fails, cluster re-balancing will be very costly.